# How to Take Derivative of Interpolating Function?

Tags: numerics, interpolation, calculus-and-analysis

So I have two numerical differentialequations which yield a InterpolatingFunction each, `potentialup` and `potentialdown`. I have merged these two functions into one graph and everything appears to work fine. However, now I want to plot their respective derivative in a graph as well. I have tried with the following command:

`Show[Plot[ND[potentialup, x, xprim], {xprim, -80, 0}],
 Plot[ND[potentialdown, x, xprim], {xprim, 0, 100}], 
 PlotRange -> All ]`

But all I get is an empty plot. I have also tried to just calculate the derivative with for instance `ND[potentialup, x, -20]`, without result. 
Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `f = Interpolation[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}]` `D[f[x], x]`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative.html).

If your interpolating function is called `if`, then its derivative is computed by `if'`.  It evaluates to another interpolating function.

Do not use numerical approximations for the derivative.  Since interpolation is done through piecewise polynomials, symbolic differentiation is possible, and is what happens here.  Watch the effective interpolation order drop as we take successive derivatives:

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0., 2 Pi, Pi/8}];
if = Interpolation[data];

Plot[{if[x], if'[x], if''[x], if'''[x], if''''[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Integration is also possible using `Derivative[-1][if]`.